# How to move double array pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, double-pointer

I am new to pointers, so please ignore my terminology mistakes. I have tried different operations like `++**ptr` and `*++*ptr` to move pointer to next element in array but they don't have any effect.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){
    int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int *p = a;
    int **ptr = &p;
    clrscr();
    
    // To know the value
    printf("%d\t%d\t%p\t%p\t%p\n",*p,**ptr,*ptr,ptr,&p);
    
    //trying to understand this operation 
    **ptr++; 
    printf("%d\n",**ptr); //here for **ptr it should print 1 but printing 0 only

    *++*ptr; 
    printf("%d.",**ptr);//here for **ptr it should print 2 but printing 0 only
    
    getch();
}
```

Also rather than doin `int *p = a;` , can I do  `int *p[] = {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};`

Comment: Ok got it , I'll just remove those , can u please tell me like how to move `**ptr` to next value in array  i.e., 1.

Comment: For that, you want `*(*ptr + 1)`, which is just `(*ptr)[1]`.  As for moving it, you can only do that by first creating a pointer for it to point to which points to 1, i.e. change `p` to `p + 1`, then `**ptr` will reference 1.

Comment: Yes , got it. thanks.

Comment: @TomKarzes can u please tell me what `*++*ptr; `  and `*++*ptr; ` operation will do ?

Comment: If `ptr` is equal to `&p`, then `*ptr` is equal to `p`, so `*++*ptr` would be the same as `*++p`, i.e. it would incremenent `p`, then dereference it.  Was there another expression that you didn't understand?  The two in the above question are identical.

Comment: @TomKarzes I think, I typed same two times , another was `**ptr++;`

Comment: Ok, `**ptr++` is equivalent to `**(ptr++)`.  It increments `ptr`, but uses the original value in the expression since the `++` is postfix.  The value of the expression is just `**ptr`, with the side effect of incrementing `ptr`, leaving it pointing past `p`, i.e. it doesn't point to valid storage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222854/discussion-between-vishal-kamlapure-and-tom-karzes).